# Proof of Intermediate Value Theorem using bisection

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-explanation

Proof of the special case of the Intermediate Value Theorem:

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a, b]$ and suppose that:

$$
f(a) < 0 < f(b)
$$

Then there exists a number $c$ in $(a, b)$ such that $f(c) = 0$.

Consider the following proof:

> First, define $[a_0, b_0] = [a, b]$ and let $p = 1/2(a_0+b_0)$, the midpoint of $[a_0, b_0]$.
>
> If $f(p) = 0$, then the proof is complete. Otherwise define:
> $[a_1, b_1] = [a_0, p]$ if $f(p) > 0$, or $[a_1, b_1] = [p, b_0]$ if $f(p) < 0$.
>
> In either case we have:
>
> 1. $[a_1, b_1] \subseteq [a_0, b_0]$
> 2. $b_1 - a_1 = 1/2(b_0 - a_0)$
> 3. $f(a_1) < 0 < f(b_1)$
>
> Now repeat this process, bisecting $[a_1, b_1]$ to obtain $[a_2, b_2]$, etc. If at any stage, we find $f(p) = 0$, the proof is done.
>
> Otherwise we obtain a sequence of closed intervals $[a_n, b_n]$ for $n=1,2,...$ with properties
>
> 1. $[a_{n+1}, b_{n+1}] \subseteq [a_n, b_n]$
> 2. $b_n - a_n = (1/2)^n(b_0 - a_0)$
> 3. $f(a_n) < 0 < f(b_n)$
>
> Property 1 implies that $(a_n)$ is increasing and bounded above by $b_0$. Hence by the Monotone Convergence Theorem $(a_n)$ is convergent. Let $\lim _{ n \to \infty }  a_n = c$.
> ...

The proof then goes on to say that the limit of $b_n$ must also be $c$ etc.

But I'm already somewhat stuck. How can they claim that "Property 1 implies that $(a_n)$ is increasing ..."?

I understand we are repeatedly bisecting the current interval to obtain another interval half the size. Any interval along the way is bounded above by $b_0$, that's also clear. But why does the lower value of the new interval necessarily increase?

My thinking: When I'm bisecting, I find a midpoint $p$. If the midpoint is larger than $0$, then I continue the bisecting with $[a_n, p]$ and if that repeatedly happens (choosing to continue with the interval on the "left side" of the midpoint), then the sequence of lower bounds $(a_n)$ wouldn't ever increase, it always could stay at $a_0$. Is that not right?

Comment: Do you agree that $[a_{n+1}, b_{n+1}]\subseteq[a_n, b_n]$? Then it must be $a_n\le a_{n+1}\le b_{n+1}\le b_n$. You are also correct that we cannot claim that the sequence of $a_n$'s is *strictly* increasing, and that the sequence of $b_n$'s is *strictly* decreasing. Luckily, we don't need to claim that in order to apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: OK, these are fair points. I was indeed thinking about strictly increasing. Now it also makes sense that they say subsetequal for the previous interval. So, either one of the endpoints of the new interval must be "changing" when deciding how to continue after finding the midpoint. That will eventually be enough for convergence if I image it correctly.

Comment: Well, you conclude that $a_n\to c$ and $b_n\to d$ where $a_n\le c\le d\le b_n$ for all $n$, but because $b_n-a_n$ gets arbitrarily small as $n$ grows, this is only possible if $c=d$. Now the step remaining is to prove that $f(c)=f(d)=0$.

Comment: So we are bisecting the current interval, hence either $(a_n)$ will increase or $(b_n)$ will decrease. $(a_n)$ is bounded above by $b_0$ and $(b_n)$ is bounded below by $a_0$. Thus Monotone Convergence Thrm applies, say $a_n \to c$ and $b_n \to d$. for $a_n \le c \le d \le b_n$ for all $n$ and since $b_n - a_n$ gets smaller as $n \to \infty$, $c = d$ eventually. 
Since $f$ is continuous, $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) = f(c)$ and $\lim {n \to \infty} f(b_n) = f(d)$. From here we'd need to show $f(c) = f(d)$ and after that property 3 could be used to show that both are $0$, but not sure here.

Comment: But, if $c=d$, of course $f(c)=f(d)$ as $c$ and $d$ are *the same number*.